# Optimal vertex cover for graph with 7 vertices each of degree 2

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to figure out the optimal vertex cover for a graph with 7 vertices each of degree 2.

Of course, there are lots of graphs with these properties and I have been trying to construct manually some of them and found that all of them have a vertex cover consisting of **4 vertices**.

However, I am struggling finding an argument of this being true for all the cases.

My attempt is the following:

By the Handshaking Lemma, the number of edges is $\frac{2 \times 7}{2} = 7$ edges in any of these graphs. Each vertex can "handle" 2 edges at the same time. So 3 vertices can "handle" 6 edges at the same time. For the remaining edge, we select another vertex. Thus, the optimal vertex cover consists of 4 vertices.

Comment: Lots of graphs? There are only two if you restrict yourself to simple graphs, so I guess you are not assuming the graph is simple. If you're talking about loopless multigraphs (multiple edges allowed but no loops) there are still only three. If you allow loops you get an obvious counterexample: 7 vertices, a loop at each vertex, you need all 7 vertices to cover all the edges.

Comment: Your argument seems to be insufficient. Doesn't the same argument show that a graph with $9$ vertices, each of degree $2$, has a vertex cover with $5$ vertices? But the graph $C_3+C_3_C_3$ (union of three disjoint $3$-cycles) needs $6$ vertices for a vertex cover.

Answer (score 0):

If the graph is simple and connected,
it is a circuit of 7 vertices.
A vertex covet of 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 and an edge 7 - 1
is { 2, 4, 6 }.

With other graphs it can be as many as 7.
For example, seven vertices each with a loop.

Comment: @bof.  Ok, I've edited in connected.

Comment: Instead of editing in "connected" wouldn't it be better to just point out the the other possible graph, the disconnected one, also has a vertex cover of size $4$?

Comment: What vertex cover of 7 loops has 4 vertices? @bof

Comment: None, as I noted in my comment to the question. But "graph" usually means "simple graph", and there are only two **simple** graphs with $7$ vertices each of degree $2$, and they both have vertex covers of size $4$. Likewise all loopless multigraphs with $7$ vertices of degree $2$ have a vertex cover of size $4$.

Comment: In short, you could have edited in "simple" or "loopless" instead of "connected".